# OrientDB group by query using graph

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregate, orientdb

I need to perform an grouped aggregate on a property of vertices of a certain class, the group by field is however a vertex two steps away from my current node and I can't make it work.

**My case**:
The vertex A contains the property I want to aggregate on and have *n* number of vertices with label `references`. The vertex I want to group on is any of those vertices (B, C or D) *if that vertex has a `defined by` edge to vertex F*.

```
A ----references--> B --defined by--> E
  \---references--> C --defined by--> F
   \--references--> D --defined by--> G
     ...
```

The query I thought would work is:

```
select sum(property), groupOn from (
    select property, out('references')[out('definedBy').@rid = F] as groupOn from AClass
) group by groupOn
```

But it doesn't work, the inner statement gives me a strange response which isn't correct (returns no vertices) and I suspect that `out()` isn't supported for bracket conditions (the reason for the `.@rid` is that the docs I found stated that only "=" are supported.

`out('references')[out('definedBy') contains F]` doesn't work either, that returns the `out('definedBy')` for the `$current` vertex).

Anyone with an idea how to achieve this? In my example, the result I would like is the property in one column and the @rid of the C vertex in another. Then I can happily perform my group by aggregates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it! In OrientDB 2.1 (I'm trying rc4) there's a new clause called `UNWIND` (see [SELECT](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL-Query.html#unwind) in docs).

Using UNWIND I can do:

```
SELECT sum(property), groupOn from (
  SELECT property, out('references') as groupOn
  FROM AClass
  UNWIND groupOn
) WHERE groupOn.out('definedBy')=F
GROUP BY groupOn
```

It could potentially be a slow function depending on the number of vertices of AClass and its references, I'll report back if I find any performance issues.