# Querying Out from Out in OrienDB?

Tags: orientdb

Looking at the following image:

[image: Graph]

I need a query that just outputs four rows as below:

```
A1.SomeProperty, B1.SomeProperty, C1.SomeProperty
A1.SomeProperty, B1.SomeProperty, C2.SomeProperty
A1.SomeProperty, B2.SomeProperty, C3.SomeProperty
A1.SomeProperty, B2.SomeProperty, C4.SomeProperty
```

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT 
SomeProperty as A_Property
out(L1).SomeProperty as B_Property,
out(L1).out(L2).SomeProperty as C_Property
from A
UNWIND B_Property, C_Property
```

I can't get my head around UNWIND - I think the problem is following out(L1) and out(L2).

Comment: After reading up on [`SELECT`](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL-Query.html) I think you are limtied to just a single field to unwind, you might need to restore to a nested SELECT like this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/31034374/16959 but I have never used OrientDB so I don't know if this qualifies as an answer

Comment: I think you're right that I should be using a nested select. I can't get my head around the syntax for that. Will keep persevering.

Comment: I wold suggest your inner query should select your `B_Property` (and `UNWIND`) and your outer query will select your `C_Property` (and `UNWIND`)

Comment: I wonder if there is an equivalent to http://sqlfiddle.com/ but with object databases like this one, I would love to play with the query language, even a simple playground that flushed anything more than 30 minutes old

Comment: @JasonSperske, if you download the DB, there's a demo project in there. Just need to run in on localhost and open up the studio. It's pretty cool.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on v 2.2 you can use MATCH statement:

```
MATCH
  {class:A, as:a} -L1-> {as:b} -L2-> {as:c}
RETURN 
  a.SomeProperty as A_Property, 
  b.SomeProperty as B_Property, 
  c.SomeProperty as C_Property
```

If you also need the edges:

```
MATCH
  {class:A, as:a} .outE("L1"){as:edge1}.inV() {as:b} .outE("L2"){as:edge2}.inV() {as:c}
RETURN 
  a.SomeProperty as A_Property, 
  b.SomeProperty as B_Property, 
  c.SomeProperty as C_Property,
  edge1.something as xxx,
  edge2.something as yyy
```

Comment: Thanks Luigi!!

If I have As without links to Bs, or Bs without links to Cs, how do I return them in the query too?

Comment: Getting closer to this by adding optional:true to the match on C, but can't add an optional:true on B because it has an out link.

Comment: Even closer now. Need to get other properties from "Result" without unwiding

    SELECT
 a.A_Property as ID,
        b.B_Property as Name,
        b.out(Link).C_Property as Result
    FROM
    (MATCH
      {class:A, as:a} --> {optional:true, as:b}
    RETURN 
      a,b)
    UNWIND Result

Comment: in case you still didn't find it on your own, to get the edges just replace -EdgeName-> with .outE("EdgeName"){as:theEdge}.inV()

Answer (score 0):

Getting closer thanks to Luigi.

Need to get other properties from "Result" without unwiding

```
SELECT
a.A_Property as ID,
    b.B_Property as Name,
    b.out(Link).C_Property as Result
FROM
(MATCH
  {class:A, as:a} --> {optional:true, as:b}
RETURN 
  a,b)
UNWIND Result
```